# Print pixel values from Copernicus landcover

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, copernicus

I would like to export Landcover values for pixels defined in my csv table (regionCol). Even though this code works fine with other Images, it does not export the mean values (which I need) from the Landcover image.

How should I export the mean values?

Here is the code -

```
//add copernicus image
var img = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('urban-coverfraction');


//add asset
var regionCol = ee.FeatureCollection('users/jakubhrouda/rehci_3'); 

//center map, show layers
Map.setCenter(16.24, 49.70, 7);
Map.addLayer(img, {min: 1, max: 100, palette:"yellow, green"}, 'Landsat image');
Map.addLayer(regionCol, {color: 'black'}, 'Rehci');

//create var stats, calculate mean
var stats = img.reduceRegions({
  collection: regionCol,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().unweighted()
});

//print results
print('Urban coverfraction', stats);
```

And here is my code in Code Editor -
https://code.earthengine.google.com/42f2255104844de352e1747019630791

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding "crs" to the ReduceRegions parameters - it seems that while some images don't need this parameter, for others it is necessary.